# How do I integrate multiple apps into one?

Tags: android

So I want to make an app that combines apps like Snapchat, Twitter, Facebook, and Instagram all into one. The thought was that you have the main home screen and then you have buttons for each of the apps so for example if you press the Twitter button it will show you your Twitter feed and any other Twitter related things. The app doesn't have to include only those four apps, it could include any social media app you want. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: "The thought was that you have the main home screen and then you have buttons for each of the apps so for example if you press the Twitter button it will show you your Twitter feed and any other Twitter related things" -- this would seem to be precisely how they already work, where "the main home screen" is the device's home screen and "the buttons for each of the apps" is the home screen's launcher (or similar affordances, like shortcuts).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *include* apps of other developers. You can either launch that app or you can write your own code to obtain and show the same data (possibly using some libraries if these social networks have published them).

Comment: So what you're saying is my app idea isn't possible?

Comment: It is not possible in the way you want to do it